# Bash Script single quotes inside of double quotes inside of single quotes

Tags: bash

Yeah, this is kind of messed up but I have to do something like the following (this is just a simplified example):

`sudo -H -u user1 bash -c ‘ssh -I /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa -f user2@machine1.domain1.com “find ./ -name ‘*.txt’”’`

I have a need to have single quotes which are inside of double quotes which are inside of single quotes.  Doesn't seem the standard `'"'"'` would work since the doubles would close the doubles rather than quoting a single.  Would it maybe be:  `"'"'""'` for each single I need inside there?

I've tried just skipping the `'` around the ssh command but of course that failed.

Comment: First change the ‘ (opening quote) and ’ (closing quote) chars into ' (single quote). Do the same with “ and ” into " (double quotes). It looks like you edit your bash script with a text editor like MS-Word, whse behaviour is to change the pairs of quotes into an opening and a closing quote.

Comment: Second, escape the quotes inside quotes with a \ (backslash), like chepner says below.

Comment: The standard `'"'"'` would work here -- when the first level of quotes are parsed, the double-quotes (within single-quotes) aren't considered significant, they're just another character that happens to be in a quoted string. You can test this (i.e. see what the command looks like after one level of parsing & quote removal) with `printf '%s\n' 'ssh ... "find ./ -name '"'"'*.txt'"'"'"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `bash -c` layer; just run `ssh` itself directly from `sudo`.

```
sudo -H -u user1 ssh -I /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa -f user2@machine1.domain1.com "find ./ -name \"*.txt\""
```

(The `-I` option should be unnecessary; if `ssh` is run as `user1`, then the default key is `~user1/.ssh/id_rsa`. You may have meant `-i` anyway; `-I` specifies a PKCS#11 library to use, not a private key.)

That said, you cannot include single quotes inside a single-quoted string. When in doubt, use double quotes, and properly escape any nested double quotes.

Comment: Sorry, need the bash -c.  I'm going from a unix box to a winders box running cygwin ssh server.

Comment: `bash -c` runs locally; what does the OS on the remote host have to do with that?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  It works with the bash -c, but doesn't work without the bash -c

Comment: Marking this as the solution.  I had to keep the bash -c, but using escaped doubles inside of doubles and inside a single worked well.  Thanks!!!

Comment: So what command are you *actually* running, because the one in your question does not need `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

chepner's answer is sufficient. 
If `bash -c` required, this solution which looks messy can be used:

```
sudo -H -u user1 bash -c 'ssh -I /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa -f user2@machine1.domain1.com "find ./ -name '"'"'*.txt'"'"'"'
```

explanation

```
'... "find ./ -name '[first ' ended here]  "'" [second ' quote start]  '*.txt'[pattern]  "'"[second ' end] '"'[ " ended here]
```

I replaced `‘`  with `'`.

Comment: This gives me:

-bash-4.2$ ./test.sh
'*.txt": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
'*.txt": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file